# Localize enum that resides in a different project, without using SharedResources

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, localization, razor-pages, resx

In my app, I have 2 projects, MyApp.Web and MyApp.ClassLibrary project. In the `ClassLibrary` project, I have `AccountType` enum that I'm trying to localize. I'm able to achieve it using standard `SharedResources` setup, but I would like to use separate resources files for the `ClassLibrary`

The error I'm getting is:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed. Type 'MyApp.ClassLibrary.AccountResources' is not public or does not contain a public static string property with the name 'Active'.

The `AccountType` enum:

```
namespace MyApp.ClassLibrary.Accounts;

public enum AccountType
{
    [Display(Name = "Active", ResourceType = typeof(AccountResources))]
    Active,
    [Display(Name = "Disabled", ResourceType = typeof(AccountResources))]
    Disabled,
    [Display(Name = "Demo", ResourceType = typeof(AccountResources))]
    Demo
}
```

I have created a dummy class at the root of the ClassLibrary project:

```
namespace MyApp.ClassLibrary;
public class AccountResources
{
}
```

I have created Resources folder inside the Web project, and put the `Accounts.AccountResources.uz-Latn-UZ.resx` file in there.

In the `Program.cs`, my configuration is as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");


builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix).AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
            factory.Create(typeof(SharedResources));
    });
```

**Note:** You can notice that I'm using `SharedResources` here and they **do work** for the enums in the `ClassLibrary`. But I would prefer to have separate resource files for the ClassLibrary project, including localization for the enums.

The access modifier for the `Accounts.AccountResources.uz-Latn-UZ.resx` file is set to 'No code generation', the same as in `SharedResources.uz-Latn-UZ.resx` (which works).

I tried to move the `Accounts.AccountResources.uz-Latn-UZ.resx` in the Resources folder in the ClassLibrary, but I'm getting the same error.

Is this configuration wrong? Is there a proper way to achieve the required setup without using `SharedResources`?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044458/asp-net-core-localized-resource-in-separate-assembly

Comment: @QiangFu, it works fine for my other resources that use IStringLocalizer, IVIewLocalizer, etc. But for localizing enums, I'm using DataAnnodations like this: `[Display(Name = "Active", ResourceType = typeof(AccountResources))]`. For DataAnnotations, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.
Create a `AccountResources.resx` file at root, no need for register service. Set the Access Modifier as 'public'.
[image]
[image]

Product.cs

```
    public class Product
    {
        public AccountType AccountType1 { get; set; }
    }
    public enum AccountType
    {
        [Display(Name = "Active", ResourceType = typeof(AccountResources))]
        Active,
        [Display(Name = "Disabled", ResourceType = typeof(AccountResources))]
        Disabled,
        [Display(Name = "Demo", ResourceType = typeof(AccountResources))]
        Demo
    }
```

Controller

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = new Product() { accountType = AccountType.Demo };
            
            return View(result);
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication9.Models.Product
@Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>m.accountType)
```

Output
[image]

Comment: It works if I make it as you suggest. But to reproduce my problem, try to do the following: 1. Move `AccountResources.resx` and `Product` and `AccountType` to a Class library project.

Comment: 2. Try to use language specific resource file, like `AccountResources.fr.resx`. When I add language specific file, only the .resx XML file itself is generated and there is no backround C# class. So I can't see the resource with `typeof()`. Now I add a dummy `AccountResources.cs`. It gets linked to to the `fr.resx` file automatically. But when I run this setup, I get this error: `InvalidOperationException: Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed. Type 'MyApp.Domain.AccountResources' is not public or does not contain a public static string property with the name 'Active'.`