# Localization in ASP.NET Core MVC (without multiple resx for each route)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, localization

I would like to simplify how I use localization in ASP.NET Core MVC.
Currently I use the classic method provided by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-8.0. But it is exhausting.
I have too many pages, too many controllers and many views.

Creating a `.resx` file for each language will be damaging in case there is a lot of updates (and it will probably be a lot).

I tried to follow this example [Best way to implement multi-language/globalization in large .NET project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373388/best-way-to-implement-multi-language-globalization-in-large-net-project) which shows how to implement localization using console app, but failed.

I would like to use a similar method to only have 1 set of `.resx` file per language for the whole website.

If someone knows how to implement it, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the question posted.
I followed this link [Accessing localized resources from a separate project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044458/asp-net-core-localized-resource-in-separate-assembly)

Follow the original answer preferably. For .net core 6 MVC users, just use the same pattern in this answer.

To make this solution works for .net core 6 MVC (may be higher), it is necessary to

1. Target the resources.resx in the startup project, instead of a dummy class.
   `services.AddMvc().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>factory.Create(typeof(YOURPROJECTNAME.Resources));});`
2. Do not forget to also change the target in cshtml pages

````
@inject IStringLocalizer<YOURPROJECTNAME.Resources> Localizer```
````